# Equation for Axial flow compressor blade/stator vein geometry?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I've read through many PDF's on the web but can't seem to find the equations I'm after, I am trying to make a small model axial flow compressed jet engine, a little smaller then a shoe box. Any good online resources I can read up on? Much appreciated.

Comment: I am just curious, are you student or are you trying to do this on your own? The reason I ask, is because the equation for an axial flow compressor are quite complex (even in their most ideal and simplified form). The equations consist of velocity components in multiple frames of reference, so if you are not up to speed on your math/physics it will most likely be of little use.

Comment: I am not a student of it, i'm actually studying automotive engineering, Jet engines have been an interest of mine for many years, and I've only just recently had the time to take it further. I was hoping to use this as something to learn from.

Comment: I would recommend obtaining an undergraduate level text on airbreathing propulsion. I good text that will help you with your question (chapter 9) is *Elements of Propulsion: Gas Turbines and Rockets* by Jack Mattingly. Unfortunately, poking around the internet for turbomachinary equations will most likely be a failed endeavor. These equations are complex and require very careful reading to truly understand them.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will do that, I appreciate your input.

Comment: This is a resource-finding question, which is not [on-topic](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site